# Time subtraction in Aurelia

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, aurelia

I would like to print the duration of an event that occurs between 'startDateTime' and 'endDateTime', expressed in minutes or seconds (if less than 1 minute).

In other words, `${startDateTime | dateFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"}` is 2018-09-07 11:57 and `${startDateTime | dateFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"}` is 2018-09-07 13:00.
What I would like to print is `63 minutes`.

In PHP, I would do `->getTimestamp()`, but in Aurelia I have no clue what to even try.

I did test with something like `${endDateTime| dateFormat:"HH:mm:ss" - startDateTime| dateFormat:"HH:mm:ss"}` but this can't work as it doesn't convert the entire date time to seconds or minutes...

Therefore, is there a clean solution I can implement in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using a value converter.

```
import moment = require("moment");

export class DurationValueConverter {
    public toView(startAt, endAt) {
        if (!endAt) {
            // If end date is missing, use the current date and time.
            endAt = moment();
        }

        const duration = moment.duration(moment(endAt).diff(moment(startAt)));

        return duration.humanize();
    }
}
```

Usage: `${startedAt | duration:endedAt}`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to have is relative time, It's on its way to browsers, but for now, you will have to use polyfill / library for it. One you can find is from yahoo: https://github.com/yahoo/intl-relativeformat